# cardinality of a set with repeating elements?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

What is the cardinality of a set which has repeating elements ? 
For example $S = \{1,1,1,2,2\}$
Is each individual element counted? 
Please quote a reference text if possible.

Comment: A set does not have repeating elements. You may want to look at multiset that allow repeating elements http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset

Comment: if you define $\{1,1,1,2,2\}$ to be $\{1\}\cup \{1\}\cup \{ 1\}\cup \{2\}\cup \{2\}$ then $\{1,1,1,2,2\}=\{1,2\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $A = \{1,1,1,2,2\}$ is identical to the set $B = \{1, 2\}$ because one can show $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$ and therefore $A=B$. Both have cardinality 2.

For example, [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/155616/25554) I quoted Halmos:

> The *ordered pair* of *a* and *b*… is the set $(a, b)$ defined by:
>   $$(a, b) = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}.$$
>   …
>   We note first that if $a$ and $b$ happen to be equal, then the ordered pair
>   $(a, b)$ is the same as the singleton $\{\{a\}\}$.

This isn't precisely what you want, but it is a consequence of it: if $a$ and $b$ happen to be equal then the set $S = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ is $\{\{a\}, \{a, a\}\}$, and the repeated $a$ in the $\{a,a\}$ element can be ignored, since $\{a,a\} = \{a\}$.  Then $S = \{\{a\}, \{a\}\}$ and the repeated $\{a\}$ can be ignored, so $S$ is really just $\{\{a\}\}$.

That thread has a number of other references, particularly in [this post by Brian Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/155513/25554).