# What is the intersection of $\{1, 1, 2, 3\}$ and $\{1, 1, 2, 4\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have two sets: $\{1, 1, 2, 3\}$ and $\{1, 1, 2, 4\}$. What is the intersection of them? Is it $\{1, 1, 2\}$ or just $\{1, 2\}$?

Comment: Sets have unique elements, no duplicates

Comment: The answer is $\{1, 2\}$.

Comment: @eddard.stark Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the usual convention $\{1, 1, 2\}$ and $\{1, 2\}$ represent just the same set.

Refer also to [cardinality of a set with repeating elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391516/cardinality-of-a-set-with-repeating-elements) and [$\{1,1\}=\{1\}$, origin of this convention](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155475/1-1-1-origin-of-this-convention?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Note that  the equality between two sets is defined as :

$$ A=B  \iff  A\subseteq B  \text { and }  B \subseteq A $$

Thus

$$\text {{1,1,2,3}}= \text {{1,2,3}} $$

$$  \text {{1,1,2,4}}= \text {{1,2,4}} $$

$$ \text {{1,1,2,3}}\cap\text {{1,1,2,4}} =$$

$$ \text {{1,2,3}} \cap \text {{1,2,4} ={1,2}} $$

Answer (score 1):

If these are multisets rather than sets, then the [usual convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Basic_properties_and_operations) would be to say their intersection was the multiset $\{1,1,2\}$

But if these are sets rather than multisets, then your question is really

> I have two sets: $\{1,2,3\}$ and $\{1,2,4\}$. What is the intersection of them?

with the answer $\{1,2\}$ (which non-coincidentally is what $\{1,1,2\}$ really is as a set)