# Linear independence of duplicate vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question about the definition of linear independence.

I saw a definition below in my course.

**Definition** A set of vectors $\{v_1, \cdots v_n\}$ is linearly independent if the equation $c_1 v_1 +\cdots c_n v_n = 0$ has only the trivial solution $c_1 = \cdots =c_n =0$. The set is called linearly dependent otherwise.

When I saw this, I wondered: what if $v_i$ are all the same? For example, Is $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$ linearly independent?

**My thought** is that, since set with the same element $\{a,a\}$ is equal to $\{a\}$, as we see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155475/1-1-1-origin-of-this-convention), so $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\right\}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$ must hold, and this set is linearly independent.

Is this correct? if not, why?

This question arose when we were discussing the statement "$n+1$ vectors in $n$-dimensional vector space are linearly dependent". If my argument is correct, I think this would be false.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: If $v \neq 0$ then $\{v\}$ is LI but $\{v,v\}$ is not.

Comment: It's best to think of linear independence as a property of (indexed) families instead of sets. In this definition, the author either implied distinct elements when writing "a set of vectors $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$" or they really meant a family instead.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy They are the same set! The family $(v)$ is linearly independent but the family $(v,v)$ is not.